# The while loop keeps executing no matter whatever the second user input is within the second case of the switch

Tags: c++

The code has been updated in order to solve a different section of the whole picture within the coding process. Now I need help within the second case of the switch. The problem now is that the while loop always executes within the second function of the switch. I don't no if the array is verifying the number or the user input.. I could use while (string::npos != studID2[i].find_first_of(studID2[a])) I need some help here it is getting very complex and I am hitting a brick wall.

**1)I need to verify each user input using a for loop and two arrays. I tried to increment the of the arrays in order to execute the while statement.**

**2) If the condition is true the while loop will execute telling the user that he must enter 3 different digits, the reason why I am using an array and a for loop is because the user gets to choose how many names and IDs he would like to input into the archive.**

**3) The for loop increments a++ in order to check to see if the last input is the same as the newest user input.
It is getting too complex here any help would be appreciated.**

Number 4 is the expected error...

**4) The second user input will always make the while loop run regardless of what digits you use.**

**5)The reason for so much code is because I am not completely sure where the problem begins and the problem ends...**

**6)I am using two arrays here in this problem.**

**7)There is another error if you change the a from 0 to 1 it will automatically close the program. The reason you would change the a to  a 1 is so that a will increment by 1.**

```
//I am trying to verify multiple inputs with a array and a for loop..
// The expected output is that the second ID you input in the second option of the switch case is going to execute the while loop.
//I am trying to execute the while loop properly within the second function of the switch case.
//I need help any form of help can be appreciated.
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include <cstddef>    
#include <limits>
#include <cstdlib>
int name2 = 0;
int studentID = 0;
int email2 = 0;
int studentID2[100];
std::string let("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
int numbers = (1, 3, 0);
std::string str;
std::string name;
std::string studID;
std::string studID2;
std::string email;
std::string emailbackup;
std::string studFinal;
std::stringstream concatenate;
std::stringstream concatenatetwo;
int x;
std::string fileName = "StudentArchive.txt";
void emailEntry();
void readDocument();
int readNumber();
void deleteInformation();
void getStudentinformation();
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
int main()
{
    do {
        std::cout << "What would you like to do?" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "1)Would you like to see the archive?" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "2)Would you like to register student information?" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "3)Would you like to find a student within the registry?" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "4)Delete all student information?" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "5)Exit Program?" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> x;

        switch (x)
        {
        case 1:
            readDocument();
            break;
        case 2:
            emailEntry();
            break;

        case 3:
            deleteInformation();
            break;
        case 4:
            getStudentinformation();
            break;
        case 5:
            cout << "Exiting Program." << std::endl;
            system("PAUSE");
            break;
        }
    } while (x != 5);
}
void emailEntry()
{
    std::ofstream  outfile;
    outfile.open(fileName, std::ios_base::app);
    int amountofStudent;
    std::cout << "How many student Identities would you like to enter?" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> amountofStudent;

    cin.ignore();
```

Here is where the user chooses how many students he would like to enter into the registry. I am having difficulty verifying the user input regarding the studentIDs.

```
    if (outfile.is_open()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < amountofStudent; i++)
        {
            std::string studID2[100];
            std::stringstream(name) >> name2;
            cout << "Please enter your name.." << std::endl;
            getline(cin, name);
            outfile << name;
            std::stringstream(name2) >> name;
            while (std::string::npos != name.find_first_of("0123456789"))
            {
                cout << "You must have letter within user input." << std::endl;
                cout << "Please enter your name." << std::endl;
                getline(cin, name);
                outfile << name;
            }
//I need to check to see if the first 3 numbers are correct?
//The student ID must be at least 6 digits, and the first 3 numbers must be 130. 
            cout << "Please enter Your student I.D." << std::endl;
            getline(cin, studID);
            outfile << studID;
            std::stringstream(studID) >> studentID;
            while (/*std::string::npos != studID.find_first_of("130") */ studentID != 130 /*&& studID.length() <= 6*/)
            {
                std::stringstream(studentID) >> studID;
                cout << "You must enter 130 as the first 3 digits" << std::endl;
                getline(cin, studID);

                std::stringstream(studID) >> studentID;
            }
            //==============
            //std::stringstream(studentID2) >> studID2[i];
            cout << "Please enter the second part of the student I.D. " << studentID << "-" << std::endl;
            getline(cin, studID2[i]);
            outfile << studID;
            //outfile << studID2[i];
            std::stringstream(studID2[i]) >> studentID2[i];

            //cout << i;
```

This is the for loop, and array I need help with. Below this text is where I am having problems. I don't understand why the while loop won't execute I am trying to verify the first user input with the next user input. For example if the user enters 888 on the first input then tries to enter 888 on the second input they need to re-enter different digits or the input will go on forever. The main struggle is if the user chooses to enter multiple student accounts within this minor registry.

```
            for (int a = 0; a < i; i++)
            {
                while (studID2[i] == studID2[a])
                {
                    cout << "The numbers cannot be repeated you must re-enter the student ID." << std::endl;
                    std::stringstream(studentID) >> studID;
                    cout << "You must enter 130 as the first 3 digits" << std::endl;
                    getline(cin, studID);
                    std::stringstream(studID[i]) >> studentID;
                    //std::stringstream(studID2[i]) >> studentID2;
                    cout << "Please enter the second part of the student I.D. " << studentID << "-" << std::endl;
                    getline(cin, studID2[i]);
                    outfile << studID;
                    outfile << studID2[i];  
                    //std::stringstream(studID2[i]) >> studentID2;
                }
            }
```

This is where the verification of the studentIDs end...

```
            while (/*std::string::npos != studID.find_first_of("130") */ studID2[i].length() < 3 || studID2[i].length() > 3)
            {
                //stringstream(studentID) >> studID;
                cout << "Add 3 more digits." << std::endl;
                getline(cin, studID2[i]);
                outfile << studID2[i];
            }
            concatenate << studentID << "-" << studID2 << std::endl;
            studFinal = concatenate.str();
            /*while (studID.length() != 6)
            {

                cout << "You must enter 130 as the first 3 digits and you must have 6 digits." << std::endl;
                std::cin >> studID;
            }*/

            cout << "Please enter your email.." << std::endl;
            std::stringstream(email) >> email2;
            getline(cin, email);
            outfile << email;
            std::stringstream(email2) >> email;
            while (email == emailbackup || email.empty())
            {
                cout << "Please enter your email..." << std::endl;
                std::stringstream(email) >> email2;
                getline(cin, email);
                outfile << email;
                std::stringstream(email2) >> email;
            }
            concatenatetwo << email << "@atlanticu.edu" << std::endl;
            email = concatenatetwo.str();
            emailbackup = email;
            cout << "Your email is" << email << std::endl;
            std::system("pause");
        }
    }
    outfile.close();
}
```

Here is where the user deletes info..

```
void deleteInformation()
{
    std::ofstream infile(fileName, std::ios::trunc);
    if (infile.is_open()) {
        cout << "You have now have no books." << std::endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        system("cls");
        infile.close();
    }
}

void getStudentinformation()
{
    std::ifstream outfile;
    outfile.open(fileName);
    if(outfile.is_open())
    {
        int x;
        cout << "1)Name" << std::endl;
        cout << "2)studentNumber" << std::endl;
        cout << "3)Exit" << std::endl;
        cin >> x;
        switch (x)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "Please enter the student's name.." << std::endl;
            getline(cin, name);
            cout << name << std::endl;
            outfile >> name;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "Please enter the first 3 digits of the student's ID number.. " << std::endl;
            getline(cin, studID);
            cout << "Please enter the last 3 digits of the student's ID number.. " << std::endl;
            getline(cin, studID2);
            outfile >> studID;
            outfile >> studID2;
            break;
        case 3:
            std::string choice;
            cout << "Would you like to return to the main menus?" << std::endl;
            cin >> choice;
            break;
        }
    }
}
int readNumber()
{
    int number;
    cin >> number;
    std::string tmp;
    while (cin.fail())
    {
        cin.clear();
        std::getline(cin, tmp);
        cout << "Only numbers please: ";
        cin >> number;
    }
    getline(cin, tmp);
    return number;
}
```

Here is where the user reads the txt doc.

```
void readDocument()
{
    std::ifstream infile;
    infile.open(fileName);
    if (infile.is_open()) {
        std::string info;
        while (getline(infile, info))
        {
            cout << info << std::endl;
        }
        infile.close();
    }
    else {
        cout << fileName << " doesn't exists !" << std::endl;
    }
    std::system("PAUSE");
    std::system("cls");
}
//std::ofstream  outfile;
//outfile.open(fileName, ios_base::app);
//if(outfile.is_open()) {
//  cout << "How many books do you want to add: ";
//  int n = readNumber();
//  while (n <= 0)
//  {
//      cout << "Only positive numbers, please: ";
//      n = readNumber();
//  }
//  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
//      string title = "Book's Title: ";
//      cout << title;
//      title += readText();
//      string author = "Author: ";
//      cout << author;
//      author += readText();
//      string genre = "Book's Genre: ";
//      cout << genre;
//      genre += readText();
//      cout << endl;
//      outfile << title << endl;
//      outfile << author << endl;
//      outfile << genre << endl << endl;
//  }
//}
//  outfile.close();
//  cout << "Books have been added to the library !" << endl;
//  system("PAUSE");
//  system("cls");
```

Comment: Why do you have an argument for `void email()`. You have an argument `emailbackup` and then you also define variable inside the function `emailbackup`. This does not make sense.

Comment: I just have to remove the parameter.

Comment: Thank you very much you helped a lot man @Tagger5926 If I could flag up your comment I would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about your function signature.

`void email(string emailbackup);`

Do you actually want the caller to pass a string to the function `email()`?

Because you then define emailbackup inside the function again.

You want something like this probably...

```
...
    case 2:
        const string backup = "backup@email";
        email(backup);
        break;
...
void email(string emailbackup)
{
    // string emailbackup; // delete this line
...
}
```

Also, remove `using namespace std;` and be consistent with your namespace usage. Why add `using namespace cout, cin` etc if you are calling them with the namespace explicitly i.e. std::cin, std::cout.

Either add `using namespace std::cout` and use `cout` rather than `std::cout` or vice versa. Don't mix it up. Same with `std::string` and `string`. Makes it look like you defined your own string...

Just one last thing, for the sake of readability I would suggest breaking this email function into smaller functions. For instance:

```
void email(string emailbackup)
{
...
    int studentID = getStudentID();
    string studentEmail = getStudentEmail();
...
}

int getStudentID()
{
    int studentID;
    cout << "Please enter Your student I.D." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> studID;

    stringstream(studID) >> studentID;

    while (/*std::string::npos != studID.find_first_of("130") */ studentID != 130 /*&& studID.length() <= 6*/)
   {
       stringstream(studentID) >> studID;
       cout << "You must enter 130 as the first 3 digits" << std::endl;
       std::cin >> studID;
       stringstream(studID) >> studentID;

    }
    return studentID;
}
```

Comment: You are right why did I even need a parameter in the first place. The void was going to work without the parameter.

Comment: I know what you are talking about for some reason the debugger starts throwing errors at the couts. Calling cout ambiguous and cin ambiguous. It sucks when writing lines and lines of code then all of a sudden your debugger starts throwing off random errors at the cins and couts. I don't know why...maybe my version of microsoft vs is buggy.

Comment: Sounds like a workaround. Maybe if you run into those problems again you can update me. I'm quite interested in why you would get ambiguity errors.

Anyways, I added one last point so that it is easier to debug. And probably make your function name a bit more meaningful then `email()` because obviously from the name itself, I can't really tell what you are doing. It's just a good habit to get into.

Comment: I am going to break up the program into more functions as well then I will rename the void function thank you!

Comment: I just have gotten used to being sloppy. I need to improve the code to be more clean.

Comment: Also right now system("PAUSE") is ambiguous. @Tagger5926

Comment: `#include <cstdlib>` try `std::system()`. Unless system() is also defined elsewhere? Does Windows API also have `system()` defined somewhere?

Comment: Ok thank you for the tip. Is there anyway I can friend you on here?

Comment: Also, get rid of using `namespace std;`. It could be causing a lot problems due to multiple definitions or something along the lines.

Comment: What you said worked the errors are gone. @Tagger5926

Comment: Okay, nice. You can also consider using `enum UserOptions { BACKUP, SUBMIT };` and do `case BACKUP:` instead of `case 0:`. It makes your code self documenting and more human readable in a sense.